# How to write a form in different line in html?

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to display a form in different lines but i am getting it in same line.
Code -

```
    <form action="/compose" method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <label for="">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="postTitle">
        <label for="">Post</label>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="postPost"></textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">Publish</button>
    </form>
```

[image]
This is what I am getting. Do i need to add container-fluid class of bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this simplest is to use `<br>` tag
This tag break the code into line

```html
<form action="/compose" method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <label >Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="postTitle">
        <br/>
        <label for="">Post</label>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="postPost"></textarea>
        <br/>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">Publish</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do add each input tag inside its corresponding Label, after that set the label styles to `display: block`.

```
<form action="/compose" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="">
       Title
       <input type="text" name="postTitle">
    </label>
    <label for="">Post
       <textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="postPost"></textarea>
    </label>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">Publish</button>**strong text**
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lots. Can we also use bootstrap class 'form-control'?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this.

**1. Use a break after each input:**

```
<form>
   <label for="title">Title</label>
   <br>
   <input type="text" name="title" value="">
</form>
```

**2. Use CSS**

```
form {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the pre tag and wrap the form inside it, (for very simple form if not using bootstrap)
pre

```html
<pre>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="">
        <label>Age</label>
        <input type="text" name="age" id="">
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
</pre>
```